# A difficult Limit Problem

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$, evaluate

$$ f(x)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{x^n}{n(1+x^{2n})} \right|^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Numerical evidence seems to support a conjectured answer of

$$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       -\frac{1}{x} & : x<-1\\
       |x| & :|x|\leq 1 \\
       \frac{1}{x} &: x>1
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

Any help on this one? Of course it can be written as

$$f(x)= |x|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{1}{n(1+x^{2n})} \right|^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

which I assume can be L'Hopotalized, however any work I've tried seems to just get really..messy.

Comment: You can squeeze $n^{-1/n}\to 1$ out of the limit too. Now you have $1+x^{2n}\to (x^2)^n$  for $|x|>1$ and $1+x^{2n}\to 1$ for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your conjencture is correct.

Consider the term of $\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$ at $n\to\infty$

For $|x|<1$ this is asymptotically equivalent to $x^n$.

For $|x|>1$ this is asymptotically equivalent to $\dfrac{1}{x^n}$.

Does that help?

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of using $a_{n} \rightarrow L$ implies that $a_{n}^{1/M} \rightarrow L^{1/M}$ Thanks, this should simplify things immensely.